# How to show large ssrs reports on the browser

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We wanted to show data on browser from reporting server, but sometime it's failing to load and taking more than 3 mins. Is there any better approach to get the data faster.

Answer (score 0):

It can be many factors why your report is slow or failing to load. First step would be analyzing executionlog (on server where is reporting services installed, database of report server, probaby ReportServer db, view ExecutionLog2). There you can see three crutial columns TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing and TimeRendering

Extract from [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/248e5da9-e336-4ac4-a2fe-8279ef6b74e8/timedataretrieval-vs-timeprocessing-vs-timerendering?forum=sqlreportingservices) discussion

- TimeDataRetrieval - contains the sum of all DataSet durations
- TimeProcessing - The number of milliseconds spent in the processing engine for the request
- TimeRendering - The number of milliseconds spent after the Rendering Object Model is exposed to the rendering extension

That way you will know if you need to tune your query or your report and that's the good start.